# Creating a zone related clock

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a working clock for my local server and for my browser (local system). Both works great. 
Now what I want to do is find the time offset between the clocks, based on seconds, and add it to the local system clock.

For example: my system clock is: 10:00:00 and the server clock is 12:15:00 at the same date.
then the offset will be: 02:15:00 (of course it will be in seconds but just for the example I wrote it that way). And then add it to (browser)local time so I eventually get to show the server time. 12:15:00.

This is what I'm doing here:

```
var interval = self.setInterval(function(){
  clock();
},1000);

function clock()
{   
    //Get local server time
    <?php $today = getdate(); ?>;
    var ser = <?php echo $today[0]; ?>;

    //Local client time
    var seconds = Date.now();
    var offset = seconds-ser*1000;
    parseInt(offset/1000);

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(Date.now()-offset);
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();

    if(s < 10)
      s = "0" + s;
    if(m < 10)
      m = "0" + m;
    if(h < 10)
      h = "0" + h;

    var tm = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    document.getElementById("clock").value = tm;
}
```

But as soon as I put the variable

```
offset
```

in this line: `d.setTime(Date.now()-offset);`

The clock doesn't updates anymore. I guess there is an issue with PHP compatibility.
Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset calculation has to be outside of the repeadly called function:

```
//Get local server time
<?php $today = getdate(); ?>;
var ser = <?php echo $today[0]; ?>;

//Local client time
var seconds = Date.now();
var offset = seconds-ser*1000;
parseInt(offset/1000); // BY THE WAY: As the returnval of parseInt isn't stored anywhere, this line does nothing

var interval = self.setInterval(function(){
  clock();
},1000);

function clock()
{   

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(Date.now()-offset);
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();

    if(s < 10)
      s = "0" + s;
    if(m < 10)
      m = "0" + m;
    if(h < 10)
      h = "0" + h;

    var tm = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    document.getElementById("clock").value = tm;
}
```

Comment: Yes, It does suppose to be outside the function. Now the clock is ticking again. And as pointed you and @briosheje pointed, a silly mistake with the parseInt() store. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're missing something with "parseInt"?

parseInt requires a variable to store the value.

So, if you write:

```
var offset = seconds-ser*1000;
    parseInt(offset/1000);
```

Is like if you write:

```
var offset = seconds-ser*1000;
```

So, replace:

```
    var offset = seconds-ser*1000;
    parseInt(offset/1000);
```

with this:

```
var offset = seconds-ser*1000;
offset = parseInt(offset/1000);
```

Tried on my browser and works.

The whole script should look like this (I used console.log instead):

```
var interval = self.setInterval(function(){
              clock();
            },1000);

            function clock()
            {   
                //Get local server time
                <?php $today = getdate(); ?>;
                var ser = new Date(<?php echo $today[0]; ?>);
                var seconds = Date.now();
                var offset = seconds-ser*1000;
                offset = parseInt(offset/1000);

                //Local client time


                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(Date.now()-offset);
                var h = d.getHours();
                var m = d.getMinutes();
                var s = d.getSeconds();

                if(s < 10)
                  s = "0" + s;
                if(m < 10)
                  m = "0" + m;
                if(h < 10)
                  h = "0" + h;

                var tm = h+":"+m+":"+s;
                console.log(tm);
            }
```

Just parse your console.log where it needs to be parsed.

Comment: If i do this: offset = parseInt(offset/1000); then the clock is working but if I do this: offset = parseInt(offset); the clock stops.

Comment: Perhaps parseInt(offset) not divided by 1000 is too big to be subtracted to the date? What is the problem? You need to divide by offset or by offset/1000?

Comment: That indeed was the issue but as soon as I placed the code outside the function, it started working and the math manipulation is necessary because getdate() returns in milliseconds and Date.Now() returns in seconds. That's why I did it. Anyway, sorry if I made it unclear and thanks for the help.